# Showing that the best uniform approximation is unique; is this proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

Let $\mathbb{P}_n$ be the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$. If $f \in C[a, b]$, we say that a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{P}_n$ a best uniform approximation (BUA) of $f$ if it solves
$$\min_{p \in \mathbb{P}_n }||f(x) - p(x)||_{\infty} = \min_{p \in \mathbb{P}_n } \max_{a \le x \le b} |f(x) - p(x)|.$$

I know that for each $n$ a BUA exists, but I have to prove uniqueness of the BUA. I am allowed to use [Chebyshev's Equioscillation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equioscillation_theorem).

I wrote up the following proof a year ago for class, but the professor said it was wrong. However, looking back at it now, I still cannot find a mistake. Can you please let me know if it's correct? I have written in red where the professor said the mistake is. Thank you very much!

---

Throughout this proof, $|| \cdot ||$ means $|| \cdot ||_{\infty, [a, b]}.$

For any $f \in C[a, b]$, let $E_n(f) = \min_{p \in \mathbb{P}_n} ||f-p||_{\infty, [a,b]}$. The claim is obvious if $f \in \mathbb{P}_n$, so we assume otherwise.
Let $p,q \in \mathbb{P}_n$ be two BUA's of $f$.

$\textbf{Claim:}$ $r = \frac 12 (p+q)$ is also a BUA of $f$ on $[a, b]$.

*Proof:* We have
$$||f - r|| = ||f - \frac 12 (p+q)|| = ||\frac 12(f-p) + \frac 12 (f-q)|| \le \frac 12 ||f-p|| + \frac 12 ||f-q||$$
$$= \frac 12 E_n(f) + \frac 12 E_n(f) = E_n(f).$$

Since $r$ is also in $\mathbb{P}_n$, we also have $||f-r|| \ge E_n(f)$, so $||f-r||= E_n(f)$.

---

By Chebyshev's Equioscillation Theorem, $|r-f|$ achieves its maximum magnitude at $n+2$ points in

$[a, b]$. Let $y$ be any one of those points.  We have

\begin{align*}
E_n(f) &= |f(y) - r(y)| = \left| f(y) - \frac 12 (p(y)+q(y)) \right| \\
\\
&\le \frac 12 |f(y) - p(y)| + \frac 12 |f(y) - q(y)|
\end{align*}
Now, we claim that $|f(y) - p(y)| = |f(y) - q(y)| = E_n(f).$ Indeed,

\begin{align*}
E_n(f) \le  \frac 12 |f(y) - p(y)| + \frac 12 |f(y) - q(y)| \le \frac 12 |f(y) - p(y)|  + \frac 12 E_n(f).
\end{align*}
Subtracting, $\frac 12 E_n(f)$ from both sides and multiplying by $2$, we get

$$E_n(f) \le |f(y) - p(y)|$$

and combining this with $|f(y) - p(y)| \le E_n(f)$, we get equality. A very similar argument shows that $|f(y) - q(y)| = E_n(f)$ as well.

Now, we have $|f(y) - p(y)| = |f(y) - q(y)|$. Either $f(y) - p(y) = f(y) - q(y)$, or $f(y) - p(y) = q(y) - f(y)$.

If $f(y) - p(y) = q(y) - f(y)$, then
$$2f(y) - (p(y) + q(y)) = 0$$
$$f(y) - \frac 12 (p(y)+q(y))=0$$
so $E_n(f) = f(y) - r(y) = 0$, $\color{red}{\text{which implies that}}$ $f = r$ on $[a, b]$. But this is a contradiction, because $f \not \in \mathbb{P}_{n, [a, b]}$.

Therefore  $f(y) - p(y) = f(y) - q(y)$, so $p(y) = q(y)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, we have that $p$ and $q$ are equal at $n+2$ points. Since $p, q \in \mathbb{P}_n$, we have that $p=q$, so the BUA is unique.

$\color{red}{\text{The comment from the professor was: argument doesn't work because y is only one point at which the max is achieved,}}$

$\color{red}{\text{not all of them}}$. I don't know if the professor misunderstood, but $y$ was an *arbitrary* point of the $n+2$ points where the maximum is achieved.

Comment: There is a problem in your disjonction. You have ()−()=()−() or ()−()=()−() for each $y$, where $y$ is taken among the $n+2$ points where the maximum is achieved. You don't have necessarily the first case for all $y$, or the second case for all $y$. You can have the first case for some $y$, and the second case for some $y$.

Comment: @DLeMeur Thank you so much for your comment! But I think I proved that $f(y) - p(y) = q(y) - f(y)$ is a contradiction for every $y$, therefore this option cannot happen for any $y$, so for all $y$ we must have  $f(y)−p(y)=f(y)−q(y)$.